# Video playback on mousemove, not fully working

Tags: javascript

I have this script on my web.
The idea is to play the video as long as the mouse goes right or left. It's working, but I can't get it working properly on Chrome and Mozilla. Suprisingly, it works fluid on Internet Explorer...

Could you help me? Maybe you have a better idea... here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var mouseX;
  $(document).mousemove( function(e) {
        mouseX = e.pageX; 


        var timV = $("#bkvid").get(0).duration;
        var valV = (timV*mouseX/$(window).width());
        $("#bkvid").get(0).currentTime = valV;

  });
</script>

</head>

<div class="videos">
 <video width="640" height="540" id="bkvid">
    <source src="img/olasbn.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="img/olasbn.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="img/olasbn.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> 
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: My web is dgdoa.com.ar, you can see it working there.

Answer (score 0):

Because you put the video properties in the div instead of in the video tag. You should have something like this:  `<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>`

Comment: I deleted autoplay loop as I want to play just when the mouse moves. I edited the code so it's like what I have now. Firefox and Internet works now. Maybe cause I added ogg and webm formats, but Chrome plays really slow. It seems as if the mouse move is detected with large moves and not cotinuosly. Thanks for your support, @gal007.